# ¿Cómo puedo mostar un desplegable con la música disponible con pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

¿Cómo podría hacer para mostrar toda la lista de música disponible? Soy muy novato en Python y me gustaría aprender cómo hacer un "desplegable" con toda la música disponible (quizás que pregunte la carpeta donde tengo guardada la música? Estoy utilizando pygame de librería. Gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener una lista de todos los archivos .mp3 en la carpeta del programa con el siguiente codigo:

```
from os import scandir

lista_musicas = [file.name for file in scandir(".") if(file.is_file() and file.name.endswith(".mp3"))]
```

Puedes hacer las alteraciones que necesites a este codigo para lograr tu proposito.

El asunto de crear una GUI en pygame es mas complicado. Este link podría ayudar:
https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/752369

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada FunMoonicorn